# Как преобразовать unicode в utf8?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Использую `imaplib` для получения почты. Тело письма выглядит таким образом

```
'\\u0417\\u0434\\u0440\\u0430\\u0432 ...'
```

Пробую вот так

```
mail.body.encode('unicode-escape').decode('unicode-escape')
```

На выходе такая же строка

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте сделать так

```
mail.body.encode('utf-8').decode('unicode-escape')
```

Comment: <div>РџСЂРѕРІРСЂРєР СЃРІСЏРРёРџСЂРѕРІРСЂРєР СЃРІСЏРРёРџСЂРѕРІРСЂРєР СЃРІСЏРРёРџСЂРѕРІРСЂРєР СЃРІСЏРРёРџСЂРѕРІРСЂРєР СЃРІСЏРРёРџСЂРѕРІРСЂРєР СЃРІСЏРРёРџСЂРѕРІРСЂРєР СЃРІСЏРРёРџСЂРѕРІРСЂРєР СЃРІСЏРРёРџСЂРѕРІРСЂРєР СЃРІСЏРРёРџСЂРѕРІРСЂРєР СЃРІСЏРРёРџСЂРѕРІРСЂРєР СЃРІСЏРРёРџСЂРѕРІРСЂРєР СЃРІСЏРРёРџСЂРѕРІРСЂРєР СЃРІСЏРРё</div>'

Comment: вот такой код на выходе

Comment: Странно, у меня все нормально выводится. А сами исходники в какой кодировке? Не пробовали в начале скрипта указывать `# -*- coding: utf8 -*-`?

Comment: @Radzhab, значит у вас на самом деле не те данные на входе, какие вы показываете в вопросе.